# Counting lines from a csv file

Tags: java, file, loops, csv

I am trying to count the amount of r,t, and c's in the below csv file.

I am currently returning the values 4 c's 0 r's and 3 t's, which is not an accurate result. Can someone help me identify the error in my code?

```
public static int getCount ( String fileName, String letter )
{
int count = 0;
String line;
String[] lineArray new String[3];  
Scanner sc = new Scanner (System.in);  
try  
{  
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName));  
    count = 0;  
    while (br.readLine() != null)  
    {  
        line = br.readLine();  
        lineArray = line.split(",");  
        for (int i = 0; i < lineArray.length; i++)  
        {  
(lineArray[0].equals(letter))count++;  
        }  
    }  
    br.close();  
}  
return count;  
}
```

I am reading off a csv file.

```
r,21.2,12.2  
c,50  
t,23.4,56.8  
t,15.3,12.2  
c,32  
t,32.3,23.5
```

Comment: Your code doesn't even compile

Comment: Agree there are issues with your sample code including not declaring letter.  I'd guess the reason why you're having issues is with the way you're handling `letter`.  use a hashmap if you're trying to keep track of frequency

Comment: Seems that you only need the 1st character, so why do you use split...
Just take the first char of "line"

Comment: I suppose it's a `if` inside the for but I didn't take freedom to modify code

Comment: yeah sorry about that i left out my method it has been updated @Emax

Comment: There is no point of the second parameter (`letter`) to your method

Answer (score 3):

The posted code won't compile, but this line:

```
while (br.readLine() != null)
```

reads a line but does not assign it to a variable so the value is lost.

Then within the loop this line:

```
line = br.readLine();
```

reads the **next line** and does assign it to a variable.  So each iteration essentially skips a line.

Change the loop condition to:

```
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null)
```

so a read line is assigned to a variable. And remove this within the loop:

```
 line = br.readLine();
```

to avoid skipping a line.

Also, instead of an array, consider using a `Map<String, Integer>` to keep track of the counts.

Comment: i tried while (line = br.readLine() != null) although it came back saying cant convert string to boolean

Comment: awesome thanks for your help i also had to remove my for loop but now it works

Answer (score 2):

Since your code doesn't compile, it's hard to tell what's wrong.
Here's an alternate solution for your problem:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        Map<String, Long> csvOccurences = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("text.csv"))
            .stream()
            .map(csvLine -> csvLine.split(",")[0])
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(csvLine -> csvLine, Collectors.counting()));

        System.out.println("c occurence -> "  + csvOccurences.getOrDefault("c", 0L));
        System.out.println("t occurence -> "  + csvOccurences.getOrDefault("t", 0L));
        System.out.println("z occurence -> "  + csvOccurences.getOrDefault("z", 0L));

    } catch (Exception exception) {
        System.err.print("Unable to elaborate the csv");
        exception.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

The code output:

```
c occurence -> 2
t occurence -> 3
z occurence -> 0
```

I'll happy to help you, but make your code compilable, so we can help you debug it.

**EDIT**:
A more **fail-safe** version of the code

```
Map<String, Long> csvOccurences =
                Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("text.csv"))   // Read the files and get all the lines
                .stream()                                   // Iterate all the lines
                .map(csvLine -> csvLine.split(","))         // Split the line into tokens (split by ',')
                .filter(csvTokens -> csvTokens.length >= 1) // Filter out all the lines that don't have at least 2 tokens
                .map(csvTokens -> csvTokens[0])             // Map the stream to only the first token
                .map(String::trim)                          // Trim the string (remove the space at start and at the end)
                .filter(csvToken -> csvToken.length() == 1) // Filter out all the token that have more than one letter (is this necessary?)
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(csvLine -> csvLine, Collectors.counting())); // Count the occurence of each letter and map them Map<Letter, Occurence>
```

Edit 2, your method fixed and refactored:

```
public static int getCount(String fileName, String letter) throws Exception {
    // Put the stream inside the try/catch so they get closed automatically
    try (FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(fileName);
         BufferedReader bufferReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader)) {
        // Initialized the counter to 0
        int letterCount = 0;
        // Declare a line buffer
        String lineBuffer;
        // While readLine is not returning null put the line inside lineBuffer
        while ((lineBuffer = bufferReader.readLine()) != null) {
            // Split the line buffer into tokens
            String[] lineTokens = lineBuffer.split(",");
            // If the tokens are more than 0 and the first token is equal to the letter
            if (lineTokens.length > 0 && lineTokens[0].equals(letter)) {
                // Increment the letter count
                letterCount++;
            }
        }
        // Return the letter count
        return letterCount;
    }
}
```

Actions taken:

- Renamed the variables
- Moved the stream (BufferedReader/FileReader) inside the try-catch
- Removed `Scanner sc = new Scanner (System.in);` it was useless
- Added a check on the length of the array `lineTokens.length > 0`
- Removed the for cycle it was useless

Comment: @GeorgesShimmon Take a look now

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple issues in your code :

- Use either `Scanner` or `BufferedReader`, not both.
- You'll need to use a `do-while` loop else the first line is getting skipped. Here we read each line and then proceed to  reading the next line.
- You are not checking whether the first index of the array matches 'r', 'c' or 't'. If it matches increment the count variable.
- You don't need the nested `for-loop` as you are splitting and parsing each line

==Code==

```
   public static int findCount(String fileName) {
       int count = 0;
       String[] lineArray = new String[3];
       try {
            Scanner br = new Scanner(new FileReader(fileName));

             do {
                lineArray = br.nextLine().split(",");
                if (lineArray[0].matches("c|r|t")) {
                    count++;
                }
             } while (br.hasNextLine());

             br.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
          // handle exception   
          e.printStackTrace();
        }   

       return count;       
   }
```

Using Java-8, we can do the entire operation in one line.

```
public static long getCount(String fileName) {
    try {
        return Files.readAllLines(Paths.get(fileName)).stream().map(line -> line.split(",")[0])
                .filter(str -> str.matches("c|r|t")).count();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your code is a method where you hand over `letter` as a String then the line where you count the letter has to be

```
if (lineArray[0].equals(letter)) count++;
```

BUT, the problem and the error with your code is the sourrounding for-loop: Here you count every occurrence of the letter three times. Remove these for-loop, as you do not need it.